# Custom Tabbar in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

Its mine 3rd day on Titanium SDK.

How can I add tab bar in my window from another .js file ? I mean I have write the code of tab bar in `createTabbar.js` and I want to add in my `firstView.js` .

Is it possible ? As I have seen many examples those have written tab bar code in app.js file so...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** :

I have **mainTab.js** that holds/returns tab bar.

**mainTab.js :**

```
CustomTabbar = function makeTab ()
{
    var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

    var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow
    ({  
        url:'TabClasses/Tab1/Tab1.js',
        navBarHidden:false,   
        title:'List 1'                 
    });

    var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab
    ({  
          icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
          window:win1
    });

    // create controls tab and root window
    var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow
    ({        
        url:'TabClasses/Tab2/Tab2.js',
        navBarHidden:false,
        title:'List 2'
    });

    var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab
    ({  
        icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
        window:win2
    });

    // create controls tab and root window
    var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow
    ({            
        url:'TabClasses/Tab3/Tab3.js',
        navBarHidden:false,
        title:'List 3'
    });

    var tab3 = Titanium.UI.createTab
    ({  
        icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
        window:win3
    });

    // create controls tab and root window
    var win4 = Titanium.UI.createWindow
    ({           
        url:'TabClasses/Tab4/Tab4.js',
        navBarHidden:false
    });

    var tab4 = Titanium.UI.createTab
    ({  
        icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
        window:win4
    });

    //  add tabs
    tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
    tabGroup.addTab(tab2);
    tabGroup.addTab(tab3);
    tabGroup.addTab(tab4);

    tabGroup.open
    ({          
        transition: Titanium.UI.iPhone && Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.NONE
    });

    return tabGroup ;
}
```

Now in my login.js file I called mainTab.js like :

```
Ti.include("mainTab.js");

loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
     if (loginSuccess)
     {
        win.close();
        var tabs = CustomTabbar();
     } 
}
```

As I am new to Titanium, if there is some better approach to do the same, please suggest me...

Answer (score 1):

See [Titanium.include](https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.include-method.html) for how to include JavaScript from one file to another.

Comment: Thanx for reply but I knew about it. I need to know some proper way to implement this as I am new to javaScript and Titanium. Can you give example code ?